# Display Rows as Column Oracle

Tags: oracle9i

My Question is simple, I would like to display rows as column:

Eg: 
Student

```
 Name  Age
 ----------
 John   10
 Paul   20
 Smith  25
```

Display information as below :

```
John  Paul  Smith
------------------
10     20     25
```

I have read about `Decode` Function, but same is not flexible.

Comment: What does "not flexible" mean to you? Are you stating that you know how to do a standard pivot of the data using `MAX(CASE ...` (or `DECODE`) but that this approach doesn't do something you need it to do? If so, what, exactly, is missing? Do you know how many columns you want in the result (or at least the maximum number of columns)? Or are you looking for a SQL statement that has a variable number of columns? Do you need separate columns or do you want delimited strings to be returned? Also, just to double-check, you're really using a 9i version of Oracle? That's pretty ancient at this point.

Comment: By Flexible, i mean its not dynamic.Yes for sure am running 9i. As per above example, how will my code adapt to a new Student in my database?

Answer (score 1):

To make the final result set dynamic ( you dont' know how many columns you'll need to pivot on ), you need to generate the query and then open a ref cursor for it.

Take a look at this link and the code listing 2 in that..

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42asktom-1653097.html